# How can i make a year picker in flutter displaying only years in list

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, flutter-layout

Please, how can i make a customized date Picker in flutter which shows only a list of years?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CupertinoPicker` widget for this.

```dart
CupertinoPicker(
  children: [listOfYear],
  itemExtent: 100,
  onSelectedItemChanged: (value) {},
)
```

More about [`CupertinoPicker`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoPicker-class.html)

Comment: You can use `List.generate(numberOfYearToGenerate, (index) => startYear+index)` with Text widget